# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, edgedriver

Creating a map to set Edge preferences

> > Map<String, Object> edgePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
> > edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
> > edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
> > edgePrefs.put("download.default_directory", file1);
> > edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
> > edgePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);

// Creating EdgeOptions and setting experimental options

> > EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
> > options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", edgePrefs);

// Adding command line arguments

> > options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
> > options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
> > options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
> > options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to Windows OS only
> > options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
> > options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
> > options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=5557");

// Setting a capability to accept insecure certificates

> > options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

// Setting up the EdgeDriver using WebDriverManager

> > WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
> > WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);

Error log:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
(chrome not reachable)
(The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)

OS -Windows 11
Java -14
Selenium 4.11
Edge version 120

I tried using selenium version 3.141.0 still facing the same issue

Any solution would be appreciated.Thank you!